# ciclo if en textview en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Soy nuevo en programando y quisiera saber como hacer que si en **android studio** un `textview` dice Perro me salga la imagen de un perro y si en ese mismo `textview` dice gato aparezca la imagen de un gato.

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, debes realizar preguntas en base a lo definido en [ask]. Realiza el [tour].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String text = textview.getText().toString();
if(text.equals("gato")){
    //posiblemente: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gato);
}else if(text.equals("perro")){
    //posiblemente: imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.perro);
}else{
    //codigo
}
```

Comment: Has realizado varias respuestas que no cumplen con lo definido en [answer] te sugiero realizarlas en base a este documento.